# Fetch an object without its relationships/children using Hibernate/JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many

I using Hibernate/JPA and I need to fetch an object without its relationship/children How can I do that? The questions is not about to use Lazy or Eager strategy because in both case the children are attached to the object, initializate or not.

Ex: I have a obj A with a onetomany relationship to B. I want to fetch a list of A without the B attached to it.

Thanks

Comment: I using this to call a method through a JAX-RS service. When I use a Lazy strategy I get a Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DTO pattern which is desirable in RESTfull services.
Be sure to have only fields that you need and you can use spring ModelMapper to convert entity to dto.

http://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application

..or implement builder (lombok) or populator/converter pattern

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading will not fetch the child records until otherwise you call for the child record's getter method. So you can use this in your case.

**Note:** In lazy loading child record will not be attached unless otherwise it's getter is invoked.

Comment: I using this to call a method through a JAX-RS service. When I use a Lazy strategy I get a Exception.

Comment: In lazy strategy if you try to access the child record once the session is closed then you will obviously get an exception. Please check this case.